# Memory (Stack) leak when using detached threads in C

Tags: embedded-linux

I have a server that creates a detached thread every time a client connects to the server and the gist of that code is here:
"

```
  tid_data.accept_skt     = accept_skt;
    tid_data.slot           = slot;
    snprintf(tid_data.client_info, sizeof(tid_data.client_info),
             "%s:%d\n", ipstr, port);
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);

    if (pthread_create(&nextThread, &attr, credsChckrThread, (void*)&tid_data) != 0) {
       CSprintf("Error: pthread_create() failed - %s", strerror(errno));
       close(accept_skt);
       continue;
    }
```

"
Here is the threadfunction (omitting functions it calls)
"

```
static  void *credsChckrThread(void *data)
{
    tid_data_t tid_data;
    int     len, slot, accept_skt;
    char    *cptr, buffer[128];
    struct timeval tv;

    memcpy(&tid_data, data, sizeof(tid_data));
    accept_skt = tid_data.accept_skt;
    slot    = tid_data.slot;

    buffer[sizeof(buffer)-1] = '\0';
    while (1) {
       tv.tv_sec    = 120;
       tv.tv_usec   = 0;
       setsockopt(accept_skt, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&tv,sizeof(struct timeval));
       len = recv(accept_skt, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1, 0);
       if (len == 0) {
          if (!errno) continue;
          // log
          break;
       }
       if (len < 0) {
          // log
          break;
       }
       // validate user - omitted
       // fill in cptr with OK or Denied -- omitted
       len = send(accept_skt, cptr, strlen(cptr)+1, 0);
       if (len <= 0) {
          // log
          break;
       }
    }
    close(accept_skt);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return NULL; // Thread exits
}
```

"

After every client connection and disconnect, I do the following and find the stack for the thread is not released:

[root@xxx tmp]# pmap 12108 | grep 10240 | wc -l
0
[root@xxx tmp]# pmap 12108 | grep 10240 | wc -l
1
[root@xxx tmp]# pmap 12108 | grep 10240 | wc -l
2

Why is the thread stack is still associated with the process?

Your help in resolving this will be appreciated.

Comment: `if (len == 0) {
          if (!errno) continue;` Note: errno is only set on an error (indicated by a return value of -1)

Comment: Are you sure the thread actually exists on disconnection? Did you check it?

Answer (score 0):

If this really is a simple memory leak you could try running your program through Valgrind.

http://valgrind.org/

Run with the flag --leak-check=full